# Rocket.Chat Livechat Internal server error

Tags: meteor, coffeescript, chat, rocket.chat

I clone master branch in my local and load `Rocket.Chat` and everything works good but I have problem with `Livechat`.

I want to <kbd>START CHAT</kbd> with `Livechat`.

1. **First step:** Enable Livechat
2. **Next Step:** Register a new account
3. **Last Step:** In `Livechat Users` section add the user to `LIVECHAT AGENTS` list.

Now by using Installation code I expect that I can chat with another user. But when I fill name and email and press <kbd>START CHAT</kbd> button I face an internal server error.

What is the problem? Any help will be appreciated

Comment: In livechat when I enter an email that dose not exist in users email, a new user created and I considered as a guest. But when I enter an email that same other emails that exist in users, an new user without name and email created and I face Internal server error. And if I repeatedly do that, many user creating with same issue.